# ¿Cómo almaceno datos en una variable y luego los muestro en netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

necesito ayuda con un ejercicio de programación mi profesor mandó hacer un formulario en netbeans java y me dijo que ese formulario almacenara los datos y luego pudiera mostrarlos, el dijo que los almacenara en un vector, pero no manero muy bien el tema, apenas estoy en primer semestre y eso es algo muy nuevo para mi.
Entonces quería saber quien tiene pues la amabilidad de explicarme o decirme como es hace, por favor.
soy nuevo, que pena :v

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es la parte física, no es un formulario como los demás.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del código, cuando pulso en el botón aceptar, solo me manda un mensaje diciendo lo que añadí, pero necesito que almacene los datos y que me permita ingresar unos nuevos y luego poder verlos.

¿Alguien sabe? ¡Help me, please!

De antemano muchas gracias por su atención y espero su pronta respuesta a mi duda.